# What is large object for JVM GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Charlie Hunt says that large object is bad for JVM GC in his [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Extreme-Performance-Java). Because:

1. Large objects are expensive to allocate and initialize.
2. Large objects of different sizes can cause Java heap fregmentation.

How to define large object? How can I know if the object is large object? Thanks

Comment: "It says" Who say that?

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay. I edited the question by adding the source.

Comment: IMHO large structures should be allocated once and reused/not discarded where possible.  This minimises the cost of creating them or any chance of fragmentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition depends on the platform, JVM and JVM configuration. For instance, here is as excerpt from [*How Garbage Collection differs in the three big JVMs*](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2011/05/11/how-garbage-collection-differs-in-the-three-big-jvms/) blog post by Michael Kopp:

> **Large and small objects**
>
> The JRockit differentiates between large and small objects during
>   allocation. *The limit for when an object is considered large depends
>   on the JVM version, the heap size, the garbage collection strategy and
>   the platform used.* (*italics* mine - DL.) It is usually somewhere between 2 and 128 KB. Large
>   objects are allocated outside thread local area in in case of a
>   generational heap directly in the old generation. This makes a lot of
>   sense when you start thinking about it. The young generation uses a
>   copy ccollection. At some point copying an object becomes more
>   expensive than traversing it in ever garbage collection.

To your second question, I am not sure how to obtain that threshold, but specifically in HotSpot you can *set* it:

`-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=2m`

Refer to the [*HotSpot JVM garbage collection options cheat sheet*](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/09/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) by Alexey Ragozin for details on this and many many other `-XX` options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no theoretical definition on its size but this will depend upon your JVM configuration for example if young generation is small then even small classes will be causing too many swaps (GC). If your objects are big enough w.r.t your JVM heap then GC will have to do more work to allocate and claim them from heap. This will lead to "stop the world" problem more often.

Answer (score -1):

Large Objects in general from GC point of view means :

- **Objects which are expensive to allocate**
- **Objects which are expensive to initialize**

Eg: arraylist of size 10000.