# How to save file in memory and read file output stream?

Tags: java, file, vaadin, java-io

When I save file I use:

```
File file = new File(filename);
```

**But, since I no longer have privileges to write to folders,** I would like rather to save it to memory and then read file to FileOutputStream.

I have read I can save file to memory with this approach:

```
new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

How would whole code look like? I can't figure it out how to write it properly after upload is done.

Edit: I'm using Vaadins upload plugin:

```
public File file;

    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename,
                                      String mimeType) {

        // Create upload stream
        FileOutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
        file = null;

        if(StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(filename, ".csv")){
            try {

                file = new File(filename);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {

                new Notification("Error", e.getMessage(), Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE)
                    .show(Page.getCurrent());
                return null;
            }
        } else {

            new Notification("Document is not .csv file", Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE)
                .show(Page.getCurrent());
            return null;
        }
        return fos; // Return the output stream to write to
    }
```

Comment: why do you need to "save" it to memory? the contents are in memory "after upload is done" (maybe as `byte[]` or `String`)

Comment: *"How would whole code look like?"* Give it a try, and come back if you have a *specific* question.

Comment: sharobn.. how can I collect those contents? My code is displayed T.J.Crowder. Question is how to collect data without writing to disc and get FileOutputStream data

Comment: You can just change this method to return `return new ByteArrayOutputStream();`. You can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` as any other `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename,
                                  String mimeType) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    return byteArrayOutputStream;
}
```

You can get the content written in the stream using:

```
byte[] dataWrittenInTheOutputStream = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Or you can write the contents to another OutputStream:

```
byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(System.out);
```

Or:

```
file = new File(filename);    
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(fos);
```

Comment: Not what I need..I don't have file saved to disc.

Comment: What do you need? How do you receive the data?

Comment: I'm not sure, that is what I'm trying to figure it out - can it be done without saving file to disc. Code is in example

Comment: Seems good, seems I need to rewrite my code without File because File is explicitly needed in my other pieces of code and this approach tells me I must avoid it then

Comment: @DavidSN how we can write `byteArrayOutputStream ` to a logger ? Any help

Answer (score 3):

1. Please avoid using ByteArrayOutputStream/ByteArrayInputStream, because they are not chunked and creates huge arrays internally
2. Please avoid using methods `.toByteArray()`, because they will require additional array allocation
3. Large allocation is not so optimal than several smaller objects allocations, because the oldest generation will be used. [See details in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190476/185498).

What is my recommendation:

1. Use `Buffer` class from [okio](https://github.com/square/okio) library. It is chunked in memory and support InputStream/OutputStream bindings
2. Use async way of data read to increase performance. However, I will show synchronous way.

So, short code will be:

```
Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
buffer.readFrom(previouslyCreatedFileStream); // of course, it is better to use    
buffer.writeTo(someOutputStream);
```