# Writing wide table (40,000+ columns) to Databricks Hive Metastore for use with AutoML

Tags: pyspark, hive, databricks, azure-databricks, automl

I want to train a regression prediction model with Azure Databricks AutoML using the GUI. The training data is very wide. All of the columns except for the response variable will be used as features.

To use the Databricks AutoML GUI I have to store the data as a table in the Hive metastore. I have a large DataFrame `df` with more than 40,000 columns.

```
print((df.count(), len(df.columns)))
(33030, 45502)
```

This data is written to a table in Hive using the following PySpark command (I believe this is standard):

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable("WIDE_TABLE")
```

Unfortunately this job does not finish within 'acceptable' time (10 hours). I cancel and hence don't have an error message.

When I reduce the number of columns with

```
df.select(df.columns[:500]).write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable("WIDE_TABLE")
```

it fares better and finishes in 9.87 minutes, so the method should work.

Can this be solved:

- With a better compute instance?
- With a better script?
- Not at all and if so, is there another approach?

[EDIT to address questions in comments]

Runtime and driver summary:

`2-16 Workers 112-896 GB Memory 32-256 Cores (Standard_DS5_v2)`

`1 Driver 56 GB Memory, 16 Cores (Same as worker)`

`Runtime10.4.x-scala2.12`

To give an impression of the timings I've added a table below.

| columns | time (mins) |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1.94 |
| 100 | 1.92 |
| 200 | 3.04 |
| 500 | 9.87 |
| 1000 | 25.91 |
| 5000 | 938.4 |

Data type of the remaining columns is `Integer`.

As far as I know I'm writing the table on the same environment that I am working on. Data flow: Azure Blob CSV -> Data read and wrangling -> PySpark DataFrame -> Hive Table. Last three steps are on the same cloud machine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course better compute instance will give you better perf. But you can try is, using script, try to write 10000 rows at a time. I know you reduced columns and it worked perfectly, i am saying try reducing rows. This way you can loop and use script to load all the data.

Comment: Could you share more information on: 1. What is your driver and executor configuration? 2. Do you have any heavy transformation in particular column? 3. What is the data type of the remaining (45502 - 500) columns? 4. How do you save the record to Hive table (e.g from local machine to other region)? Is there any possibility of networking issue?

Comment: @JonathanLam I've added some information to the question text above. Hope that helps. I've tried to use bigger machines and Photon acceleration. That did help a bit, but I've not been able to write the full table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your case is not related to either Spark resource configuration or network connection, it's related to Spark design itself.

Long in short, Spark is designed for long and narrow data, which is exactly opposite of your dataframe. When you look at your experiment, the time consuming is in exponential growth when your column size increase. Although it's about reading the csv but not writing table, you can check this post for a good explanation on why Spark is not good at handling wide dataframe: [Spark csv reading speed is very slow although I increased the number of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428195/spark-csv-reading-speed-is-very-slow-although-i-increased-the-number-of-nodes)

Although I didn't use the Azure AutoML before, based on the dataset to achieve your goal, I think you can try:

1. Try to use python pandas dataframe and Hive connection library to see if there is any performance enhancement
2. Concatenate all your column into a single Array / Vector before you write to Hive

Comment: Thanks. I was worried that this was the case. We recently switched to Databricks for other reasons and I wanted to try this wide data case there as well. Indeed, writing the wide part of the dataset (same type) to ArrayType works fine, but then I lose the ability to select those elements of the array later on as _individual_ features for training a model.

Comment: @BramVisser Although you have to concatenate all the column to a single array before you write to Hive, you can write a simple logic to retrieve the element in the array since Hive support getting item in array by index, then you can put it into AutoML and save as a new table. However, based on my understanding, Hive is also not good at handling wide dataset. If it's possible, you might consider other database like HBase.